# Spearman's rank correlation coefficient calculation

Tags: spearman-rho

I tried to calculate Spearman's rank coefficient by hand.

Data:

[image]

[image]

But when I use python, it returns a different value.

```
rawdata = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [3,4],
        [5,4],
        [6,2],
        [6,4],
        [8,9],
        [11,7]
    ],
    columns=['Set of A','Set of B'])
print(rawdata)
correlation, pval = spearmanr(rawdata)
print(f'correlation={correlation:.6f}, p-value={pval:.6f}')
```

It returns:

```
correlation=0.585239, p-value=0.222365
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you're using is a simplified version for when there are no ties. Try the full version of the formula:

$r_s=\frac{\Sigma_i(a_i-\bar{a})(b_i-\bar{b})}{\sqrt{\Sigma_i(a_i-\bar{a})^{2}(b_i-\bar{b})^{2}}}$

Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the fractional ranks you've already found in your table

Comment: You seem to be writing about the *Pearson* correlation coefficient.  The calculations presented in the question clearly deal with ties (in a standard manner).

Comment: I believe that Spearman correlation is equal to the Pearson correlation of the fractional ranks

Comment: Thank you for modifying and explaining your notation.  Doing the calculation confirms your answer is a correct explanation of the discrepancy (+1).